Looking for a specific function with integration
let t be a positive real number $t>0$. I'm looking for a function $\phi$ (independent of $t$) such that
$$\int_0^t \int_0^t \phi(u,v)dudv=t$$
Can anyone told me if such a function exist or not ?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: try separable $\phi$.

I'll try it and try so many option , the problem is that $\phi$ doesn't have to depend on t my friend , I could take it equal to $\frac{1}{t}$ but I need it to be $t$ independent. And I really appreciate your help; @J.G.

I never said to make it $t$-dependent, I know that's against the rules. By separable I mean it's of the form $f(u)g(v)$.

Suppose we have that $\phi(u,v)=\psi(u)\psi(v)$ for some function $\psi:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$\int_0^t\int_0^t\phi(u,v)\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v=\int_0^t\psi(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\int_0^t\psi(v)\,\mathrm{d}v=\left(\int_0^t\psi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2=t,$$
so we must have
$$\int_0^t\psi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{t}.$$
Differentiating we get
$$\psi(t)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}.$$
So if we let $\phi:(0,\infty)^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$\phi(u,v)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{uv}},$$
then
$$\int_0^t\int_0^t\phi(u,v)\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v=\int_0^t\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\sqrt{u}}\int_0^t\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{2\sqrt{v}}=\sqrt{t}\cdot\sqrt{t}=t$$
for all $t>0$.
